# ios filter records using nsmutablearray filled with NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend

Tags: ios

I want to filter my friends list names. I had all friends list in NSMutable array
using this method i had list .

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];

    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
        friendList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[result objectForKey:@"data"]];
        selectedfriendList =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [Tablefriendlist reloadData];
    }];
```

I want to filter records through textfield but problem I dont know how to use **`nspredicatewithformat`**

I am trying this.. and its not filtering correct searched data.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.first_name contains[c] %@",searchText];
        friendList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[friendList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
        NSLog(@"friendlist %@",friendList);
        [Tablefriendlist reloadData];
```

**I want to get friendslist that match searchtext**

problem is its fetching record but those record which contains searched characters only those.
e.g i searched sa

so it fetches records that contain character 's' and character 'a'
i want to seach records with sa    e.g ::

```
when 'sa' is searched these records should be fetched
1:falsa
2:telsa
3:salad

what is happening in my code is this
1:falsa
2:telsa
3:yalst
4:salad
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

change predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.first_name contains[c] %@",searchText];
```

to

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first_name contains[c] %@",searchText];
```

Comment: their was some other mistake in my code . now problem is solved. but   self.first_name and first_name results same output. i changed searchText with Textfield.text . and problem solved

Comment: searchText has recently typed characters not the whole text